# can't seem to get Reegex to match

Tags: java

So I was trying to get the hex colors from a string. And after some research and attempts, I reached to this code.

Here the code is:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Find out if a String contains a very simple pattern.
 */
public class PatternMatcherFind {

    private static final String HEX_PATTERN = "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String stringToSearch = "we have got white #ffffff and black #000000 wohooo!";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(HEX_PATTERN); // the pattern to search for
        Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);

        // now try to find at least one match
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println("Found a match");
        else
            System.out.println("Did not find a match");

    }
}
```

Using this, it always says that there are no matches beside we got two. If the string is just "#hex" with no other characters, it will be fine.

So what I am trying to accomplish is,
Get it to detect that there is a hex in this string and get the text after it

Example:
This string "we have got white #ffffff and black #000000 wohooo!"
Should give us

## ffffff and black

## 000000 wohooo!

I know that we can get this by
while(matcher.find()){ and then print group(0) and group(1) but my regex doesn't seem to work right now.

Comment: Try this, if it works I'll post as an answer so you can accept. `(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})(.*?)(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})` .

Comment: @shadoe2020 It did find a match, that is interesting

Comment: System.out.println(m.group(0) + " - " + m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2) + " - " + m.group(3)); gives me #ffffff and black #000000 - #ffffff -  and black  - #000000 END so the only missing thing is the last word, it is not taken into account, so whatever that is after the second hex

Comment: You should drop boundary matchers (`^$`) from your regex if it's supposed to find hexes in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Where do I put them? I tried this at the very end  \\s*(\\w+) and it then worked

Comment: In the `HEX_PATTERN`

Comment: Yeah I know but I mean, where exactly. I tried at the very first and at the end but it never worked.

Comment: @shadoe2020 any clue?

Comment: Posted an answer, not sure what else if anything comes after "Woohoo!" but this will select anything AFTER the 2nd hex also. `Try this: (#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})(.*?)(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern would not find any hex in the middle of a sentence because of boundary matchers (`^` - beginning of a line, `$` - end of a line). That's why it matches only `#hex` alike strings.

You may get rid of them, so that colours within sentence could be found:

```
private static final String HEX_PATTERN = "#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})"
```

...**but** I'm not convinced how you should proceed with that to fulfill your requirement.

Instead you may consider something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternMatcherFind {

    // ^                - String starts with
    // [A-Fa-f0-9]{6}   - 6 chars long color literal
    // |                - or
    // [A-Fa-f0-9]{3}   - 3 chars long color literal
    private static final String STARTS_WITH_COLOR_LITERAL = "^[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}";
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(STARTS_WITH_COLOR_LITERAL);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringToSearch = "we have got white #ffffff and black #000000 wohooo!";
        Arrays.stream(stringToSearch.split("#"))               // splitting on "#" will create array [ "we have got white ", "ffffff and black ", "000000 wohooo!" ]
                .skip(1)                                       // we may omit first one as it would never start with color literal
                .filter(part -> pattern.matcher(part).find())  // we keep only those Strings which starts with color literal
                .forEach(System.out::println);                 // may print them or whatever
    }
}
```

For the code above, the output is as expected:

> ffffff and black
>
> 000000 wohooo!

Comment: Aha that is pretty useful and deeply explained. thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The special character "^" only matches the beginning of the string. The special character "$" only matches the end of the string.

If you want to find the rest of the pattern in the middle of a string, don't use the special characters "^" and "$" in your pattern.